# Why is my PyQt4 program exiting the main loop for no apparent reason?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm (trying to) make a small program that resides in the system tray and checks a list of Twitch channels to see if they're online every once in a while.

I'm currently doing the GUI (in PyQt4), but it's exiting for no reason.

Here's my code so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class TwitchWatchTray(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        super(TwitchWatchTray, self).__init__(icon, parent)

        self.menu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)
        settings_action = self.menu.addAction("Settings")
        settings_action.triggered.connect(self.open_settings)

        self.menu.addSeparator()

        exit_action = self.menu.addAction("Exit")
        exit_action.triggered.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        self.setContextMenu(self.menu)
        self.show()

    def open_settings(self):
        settings = SettingsDialog()
        settings.show()

class SettingsDialog(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SettingsDialog, self).__init__()

        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('TwitchWatch Settings')
        vbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        self.channels_list = QtGui.QListView(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.channels_list)

        self.add_box = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.add_box)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    tw = TwitchWatchTray(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"), widget)

    app.exec_()
    print("Done!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I right click the tray icon and click "Settings", it flashes a white box (my dialog), then immediately exits and prints "Done!".

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons why your code exits immediately after you open the settings dialog.

The first problem is with your `open_settings` method:

```
    def open_settings(self):
        settings = SettingsDialog()
        settings.show()
```

This creates a dialog and makes it visible.  `show()` returns immediately after showing the window; it doesn't wait for the window to be closed.  The `settings` variable goes out of scope at the end of the method, and this causes the reference count of your `SettingsDialog` to drop to zero and hence become eligible for garbage collection. When Python deletes the `SettingsDialog` object, PyQt will delete the underlying C++ object, and this is what causes the dialog to close again.

I would recommend having your settings dialog subclass `QDialog` rather than `QWidget` (it is a dialog, after all).  Instead of calling `settings.show()` you can then call `settings.exec_()`.  `settings.exec_()` *does* wait for the dialog to be closed before it returns.  It also returns `QDialog.Accepted` or `QDialog.Rejected` depending on whether the user clicked OK or Cancel.  I'd also recommend getting rid of the call to `self.show()` in your `SettingsDialog` constructor.

The second problem is that your `QApplication` is set to quit when the last window is closed.  This is the default behaviour, which is what a lot of applications need, but not yours.  Even if your dialog stayed open and you could close it, you wouldn't want your application to exit immediately after you close the settings dialog.  Call `app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)` to fix this.

Comment: Thanks! That was a really really nice and in-depth explanation, and it worked!

Comment: @user1438098: glad to have helped.